# Can't update MySQL field with HTML-text from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this really strange problem that has suddenly happened. Today I noticed that I couldn't update content from our custom CMS. And I thought I'd try to just use phpMyAdmin to update the content. But when I try to do that, I get an 403 "Forbidden" error.

It looks like this happens if the text contains HTML-tags. I can update with something like "Test" or a longer "Lorum ipsum" text. But if I use HTML, then it's suddenly not possible.

It is critical for us that the CMS works. Any help at all would be greatly appriciated!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to escape html with mysql(i)_real_escape_string and htmlentities ?
Note that you sould always escape html string in database

Comment: Happened suddenly, huh?  I wonder if the MySQL GRANTs to the MySQL user id you use for update have changed?

Comment: The GRANTS looks the same.

Comment: Some overzealous security component on your web server/firewall/whatnot filtering out "invalid" requests…?

Comment: Hm. That could be the case. I’ll check.

Comment: Yes it was Cloudflare that blocked the traffic, thanks!